# pd.read_excel ignores last empty column

Tags: python, pandas, excel, openpyxl

I want to read a xlsx file with pd.read_excel:
[image: screenshot]

When I use `pd.read_excel` the last column (with number 15) isn't read (I suspect because there's no data in it) although it has grid formatting.

I could simply list all columns I want to read  in the `usecols` parameter but in general I won't know their names so I would like to find a robust way to get all columns which have any formatting (proving that they have to be read too) even though they might be empty.

Comment: May need to use `openpyxl` here. Pandas doesn't generally care about formatting like that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.